# Schengen visa for Iceland processed by the Danish embassy

Tags: visas, schengen, iceland

I am going to apply for a Schengen visa for Iceland and I read on the VFS website that it's processed by the Danish embassy.

Nowhere in the whole process do I see anything where the process differs from the Danish visa. The form is the same and even during the appointment scheduling only Denmark appears in the country list.

I called up VFS customer care and they told me that even the cover letter needs to be addressed to the Denmark embassy and not Iceland's. They told me to just mention in the cover letter details that I need a visa for Iceland.

This is making me a bit worried as I may end up getting a Denmark visa instead of Iceland quite easily.

I want to address my cover letter to the Iceland embassy. Is this the right thing to do?

EDIT:

I got my Visa and print on Visa says Denmark. And as i read now that except in China, Iceland consulates don't issue Visas, its always issues by Denmark, Norway or Sweden : https://www.worldtravelguide.net/guides/europe/iceland/passport-visa/

Comment: The vast majority of Schengen visas are issued for "Schengen states."  A visa valid for only certain states is rare and exceptional.  There is no reason to worry.  But failing to follow instructions will certainly not improve your chances of a successful application.

Comment: @phoog : But my main travel destination is Iceland.

Comment: @Lokesh There should be a field to specify that on the form so there would be no ambiguity. Besides, such arrangements are common, the consulate should know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Lokesh I know that your main destination is Iceland.  Are you aware that Iceland is a Schengen state?  If so, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: "I want to address my cover letter to the Iceland embassy." What part of "they told me that even the cover letter needs to be addressed to the Denmark embassy and not Iceland's." wasn't sufficiently clear...?

Comment: @dda : This info came from customer care and i little skeptical about it as they have changed their stance regarding another info i asked. I posted this here so anybody else who were in same situation can share their experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read on the VFS website that it's processed by the Danish embassy.

Then both Denmark and Iceland know about this. Just mention your plans correctly, and don't worry about who processes what. Tell them you want to visit Iceland. Even if the Schengen visa is issued by Denmark itself, it will be valid for Iceland as well.

And you’re applying at the Danish embassy, so address the cover letter to them and request a visit to Iceland. Had there been a visa-issuing  Icelandic mission near you, you wouldn’t have to apply somewhere else. So most probably there is no Iceland embassy for you to address anyway.

> Iceland is a part of the Schengen Agreement; this for instance secures unrestricted passage for individuals within the Schengen area. Those who enter the Schengen area go through passport control in the first country they arrive in, and then there is no further inspection. It can therefore be said that when a visa is issued for a trip to Iceland, the visa is not issued exclusively for Iceland as it gives access to all other Schengen countries.
>
> In India, the Embassy of Denmark handles visa applications for Iceland through the VFS Global in New Delhi, Chennai, Mumbai,Kolkata and Bengaluru. Information on visas and applications can be found on the websites of the Danish Embassy.

Source: [iceland.is](http://www.iceland.is/iceland-abroad/in/consular-services/visa)

Comment: So you asked them for Icelandic visa and they gave you a one only for Denmark? Are you sure? that would be highly unusual. Even if Denmark is written on it it doesnt mean its only for Denmark unless it is specifically stated there

Comment: Tp clarify, Its a Schengen states Visa, so applicable in Schengen region. What i meant was Iceland is not mentioned anywhere on Visa, so it looks like a Danish Schengen Visa.

Comment: Yeah then don't worry. Just go with your plan and visit Iceland as you wanted. Don't worry about who issued the visa

Comment: If your visa says Schengen States (or its translation in Danish) that means you will be able to enter Iceland without any issues.